# How can I update value with addition like "value = +1" in MySQL with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to calculate the addition with exisiting value.

e.g. MySQL:

```
   UPDATE TBL SET val = +1 WHERE id = 1
```

How can I do in SQLAlchemy?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the ORM or just SQLAlchemy Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the SQLAlchemy Core via just referencing the field name (example taken from [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-and-updates)):

```
>>> conn.execute(users.update().
...                     values(fullname="Fullname: " + users.c.name)
...                 )
```

In your case, this would probably look something like...

```
conn.execute(your_table.update().values(val=your_table.c.val + 1))
```

If you need more complex behavior, you can look at [correlated updates](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-updates): essentially, creating a select object that represents the new value you want (based on the old one) and setting that as the value in your update object's `values`.

Comment: Thanks! This answer was exactly what I wanted.